# SQL-style join on arrays using ECMA6

Tags: javascript, array, ecmascript-6, join

I have a code snippet which performs an SQL-style join on objects in two arrays based on a specific field (in the code below, `.id`).

```js
let preprocessed_array = [
  {id: 1,category:'a'},
  {id: 2,category:'b'},
  {id: 3,category:'b'}
] 

let new_array = [
  {id: 4},
  {id: 1,category:'b'},
  {id: 5}
] 

 for(let i=0;i< preprocessed_array.length;i++)
 {
   for(let j=0;j<new_array.length;j++)
   {
     if( preprocessed_array[i].id===new_array[j].id)
     {
       new_array[j]=preprocessed_array[i]
     }
   }
 }

 console.log(new_array)
```

Although this snippet is straightforward, I don't like the imperative style.  Is there a more declarative way to do this just with javascript / ECMA6 arrays?

Comment: Wouldn't a Join mean that when the id is already found, you get the all the categories for the shared id? Why is for example the item with id one only assigned with category a at the end?

Comment: Indeed, a joing would not be enough to get to the results I want. But it would be the core to a more declarative solution.

Answer (score 2):

Build an index and use it to map the second array:

```
const index = new Map(source.map(el => [el.id, el]));
const result = picks.map(el => (index.get(el.id) || el));
```

The larger the arrays, the more effective the index becomes.
If this code is a bottleneck, it can be rewritten to build the index on-the-go (memoization).

P.S. `source` stands for `preprocessed_array` and `picks` for `new_array` in the original code.

Comment: this answer is much better than mine +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to do the same thing "declaratively", but in my opinion that's just a stupid buzzword and yours is more readable..

```js
let preprocessed_array = [
  {id: 1,category:'a'},
  {id: 2,category:'b'},
  {id: 3,category:'b'}
] 

let new_array = [
  {id: 4},
  {id: 1,category:'b'},
  {id: 5}
] 

new_array = new_array.map(function(a) {
  var match = preprocessed_array.find(function(b) {
    return b.id === a.id;
  });
  return match === undefined ? a : match;
});

console.log(new_array)
```

Comment: You are right. Your solution is slightly more declarative, but at the same time considerably less readable. I was looking for a fully declarative style, as in sql. Now I realize, that the array objects don't provide that. So are there libraries comparable to  python pandas  to achieve what I want?

Comment: @user1934212 - there are indeed. [jSQL](https://github.com/Pamblam/jSQL/) is an SQL implementation written in js by yours truly, but doesn't yet support joins, [alaSQL](https://github.com/agershun/alasql) is a more fully featured one. [linq](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/) is basically the same thing without actaully being an SQL implementation..

Comment: Since I have a strong .NET background, I will look into the linq library first. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I personally prefer the map/find variation, but agree that the benefit is somewhat lost with your current version. I would prefer `function join(a, b) { return a.map(item => b.find(({id}) => id === item.id) || item); }`

Comment: @Gerrit0 I did that initially but the problem with that is if find returns a zero or null from the preprocessed array it will erroneously return the item from the other array. It should really check for undefined explicitly.

Comment: If we're being super picky, it should reverse the array before calling find as the ops implementation will use the last match since it doesn't break the loop on the first match.. find will return the first

Comment: Find *can't* return a zero or null from the processed array. If there is a zero or null in the processed array all three of the implementations will throw. As for reversing, I feel safe in assuming that given the key `id` it is unique.

Comment: right, in this exact case it will throw since this code requires objects with an id property. my hope was that op isn't actually writing procedural code like this tho, and i wanted it to be relatively flexible so he could turn it into a function.